# Check mongo db state for Passport

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I use the [Passport lib](http://passportjs.org/) for managing authentication in my app.

Currently, db I'm using is local:

```
mongoose.connect(dbConfig.url, {
    useMongoClient: true
});

//
// dbConfig
module.exports = {
    'url' : 'mongodb://localhost/passport'
}
```

The question is, do I have a possibility to view db state of my application? Can I change it somehow?

Comment: What do you mean by db state?

Comment: @MarkS., objects stored in my db

Comment: Sure. In case you want to use your DB content for authentication, you can use a `LocalStrategy`, implement the callback `(username, password, done)` and check whether the given credentials are allowed.

Comment: @qqilihq, yes, I know this, thanks. but I'm asking about a way to view them not from the app, but rather command line

Comment: Ok. Probably I don't fully get this, but why not just use your DB's command line tools? `mongo` for example on a MongoDB?

Comment: it's exactly what is my question about - how can I do this given only url path? question can be really silly

Comment: In case your DB runs on the localhost, it's nothing more than `mongo` on the command line. Then select your DB using `use DB_NAME`. Then write some query, such as `db['COLLECTION_NAME'].find()`.

Comment: @qqilihq, cool. thanks. it's really easy. you can convert it to answer, so I could accept it

Comment: @VladHatko Glad to hear :) I've posted it as dedicated answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case your DB runs on the localhost, it's nothing more than `mongo` on the command line to open a [MongoDB shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/shell/client/):

```
$ mongo
```

Then, select your DB by `use name-of-database`:

```
> use name-of-database
```

Then write some query for a collection within that database. The following will simply output all documents in the collection with `collection-name`. In case there are many documents, you can iterate (follow the given instructions):

```
> db['collection-name'].find()
```